# Why am I getting "Entity class must be annotated with @Entity" error and how can I ignore it?

Tags: android, annotations, android-room

I have a Lombok-annotated POJO that I'm using for other parts of the app and is not intended for Room.  But when I try to build my project I get the `Entity class must be annotated with @Entity` error about it and the build fails.

I know I could just force one of my actual Room entities to fill this data object's role by adding a bunch of `@Ignore`d fields, but that seems dumb. How can I tell it that this class is not an entity and that Room should leave it alone?

This is the class it complains about:

```
import androidx.annotation.DrawableRes;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Value;

@Value
@Builder
public class MyPOJO {
    final String matchQuality;
    final String identifier;
    final String fitDate;
    @DrawableRes
    final int image;
}
```

Comment: Note: This happens even if I remove the Lombok annotations and include manual implementations of the constructor, getters/setters, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my bad.

When I was just starting with my implementation and hadn't made any entities, I needed something to go in the Database entities annotation and put `MyPOJO` there as a placeholder:

```
@Database(entities = {MyPOJO.class}, version = 1)
abstract public class MyDB extends RoomDatabase {
```

Once I replaced this with my actual `@Entity` classes, I no longer get this build error.